# Is slack-node NPM package TLS v1.2 compliant?

Tags: node.js, slack

I have been looking for answers from Slack and digging deep into the node_modules packages and basically I am trying to figure out whether the NPM package 'slack-node' overrides the TLS version of the request. This line of investigation is brought by TLS v1.1 and below being deprecated.

I am not that good into reading packages itself but what I know is that the server itself is TLS v1.2 and am just wondering whether the package itself overrides the TLS version for some reason, however unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slack-node` uses `requestretry`, `requestretry` uses `request` and request uses `https` module.`https` module uses TLS set by Nodejs by default. If Nodejs using tls1.2 and so `slack-node` unless configured to use other versions of TLS.